# Creación de rectangulo con dos puntos

Tags: android, google-maps

Hola que tal buenas a todos. Estoy trabajando con la API de google maps en android y lo que necesito es crear un rectángulo (4 puntos) teniendo solo dos (el punto superior izquierdo y el inferior derecho). He probado muchas cosas pero ninguno me es exacto, básicamente es calcular los otros dos puntos sobrantes. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo idea de como programar con la API de Google pero es relativamente sencillo, solo tienes que ver las coordenadas. Ya que solo nesesitas 2 puntos, tienes que ver donde empieza y donde acaba, creo que con esta ilustracion quedara mas que claro...

[image: rect]

Aplica la misma idea para los demas puntos, resta la longitud o suma la altura dependiendo de que nesesites, lo unico que nesesitas es sacar las distancias entre un par de puntos, y como ya los tienes, los puedes halllar,  espero que ayude.

Comment: Si si, gracias ya lo pude solucionar !!

Comment: @JBeccaceci marca mi respuesta con el check verde para cerrar el hilo